# Software I can replicate this notebook with

Tags: drawing

I am looking for a way to practise and replicate this notebook. I am looking forward for a transparent png, but transparency is not that important.
[image]

Any software or tutorial relevant to this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the spiral graphic to be a photo, painting, or vector drawing? You mention replicate this image, but how do you want it replicated? What have you already tried?

Comment: @AndrewH My main problem is the spirals. I am curently on trying Gradient Overlay, Bevel and Emboss and adding shadows in photoshop, but I am not sure how to fully make the edge of the spiral look so shiny. Also another way I see is to clone stamp it, but I want to create it myself. I am not setup fully on the technique yet or if there is a better way and software that will help me replicate it as an exact copy.

Comment: I would just spend 2$ and get a stock photo, use the other 49-73 hours of learning how to do this properly, for something else.

Comment: If you're just going for general practice, I think you might have to change your approach... I mean it works if you want to make a vectorized version of it (at least in terms of looks), but if you do want something that tips towards realism, you're better off "painting" it: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8a37.jpg) forgot to mention in the image, but I changed the dodge tool `range` setting all the time too. - Or if you're not looking for practice, as mentioned, a good quality photo would probably be the way to go. It wouldn't be that hard to cut out the background from a photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator can be used to make book lookalikes. It's not especially difficult if one has practiced well basic operations and doesn't expect full photorealistic look. You can find in GDSE several book mockup -cases which have got answers and some of them have used Illustrator. The finest works, of course, are based on advanced 3D programs and knowledge how to use them.

An example: [Creating 3D book cover mockups from scratch](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113641/creating-3d-book-cover-mockups-from-scratch)

Books with a spiral binding are not common in GDSE. I have hanged around few years, but haven't seen here any.

Often the binding isn't spiral at all. I guess your example also is bound by a spring like this (only a short piece to show the bending idea):

[image]

The arcs are straightened temporarily and all pages are placed at the same time.

That spring is quite easy to make in a 3D program, but making an image of a book doesn't need it, because the tricky bendings are hidden behind the pages. You need only the arcs and they are much simpler. The next "book" is made in Illustrator:

[image]

Here's a zoom in view which reveals the binding better:

[image]

It's not perfect. The pages are not at all curved, their edges are too simple, they are like drawn straight lines, not a bunch of white sheets of paper. There's also no perspective.

The "book" can be exploded to parts:

[image]

1. Blurred black rectangle, it's the shadow
2. Left side bunch of pages. It's made by blending the top and bottom sheet. The blend is expanded and ungrouped because the top page must be lifted in the layering stack to cover the lower half of the binding spring
3. The fake binding spring - only rings. See more of it later.
4. Dark grey background seen through the holes (black looks too dark).
5. Right side bunch of pages. It's a mirrored copy of the left side bunch.

The fake binding spring is made with Illustrator's 3D Revolve effect. 50 small light grey circles are grouped and the group is revolved. Actually it's not revolved full 360 degrees, there are 2 separate 180 degrees revolutions:

[image]

Division to 2 parts is needed because the upper half of the spring should be in front of all pages, but the top pages should cover the lower half. The rest of the pages are behind the lower half of the spring. In high zoom image the seam between the halves can be seen. That problem doesn't occur with proper 3D models.

Illustrator's 3D effects can have perspective, but that makes combining the parts very complex. In Illustrator there's no way to make at the same time the page bunches and the spring.

One could say that there's the perspective transformation - use it! It would make the book look very thin and the spring would look like someone had stepped it flat. I skipped the perspective.

In 3D programs the perspective is no problem at all, because it's created automatically in the the rendering of the 3D model. There's no need to worry it when building the 3D model.